# How can I pass the objects from Parent component to the Child component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Here HousingAppComponent is my parent class and I want to pass this
    view object to my child component CoursesComponent so that I can display 
    the members from the view object in the courses.html page.

```
export class HousingAppComponent {


views: Object[] = [
{
  name: "Courses",
  description: "Show the courses",
  icon: "assignment"
},

{
  name: "Users",
  description: "Check your Progress",
  icon: "account_circle"
}
];
```

Comment: Use an input property on the child component: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs.  You can pass reference types like objects and array, in addition to primitive types like strings, numbers, and booleans.

Comment: Could you show me in the plunker? I have tried but its not working

Comment: @Rich's answer should work for you.  If it doesn't let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to pass data to a child component is with [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding). The view of HousingAppComponent will pass the `views` property to CoursesComponent. See the following:

housing-app.component.html:

```
<courses [someData]="views"></courses>
```

courses.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class CoursesComponent {
    @Input() someData: any;
}
```

The `[someData]="views"` notation means that you are setting the `CoursesComponent.someData` property with an expression that is evaluated between the quotation marks. It evaluates `"views"` as the `HousingAppComponent.views` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@viewchild` annotations to have a reference of child in parent and use that to pass any data. Please not the child will be available only after ngAfterViewInit lifecycle event.

`@Viewchild(CourseComponent)
cc:CourseComponent
cc.Course = data`

You can also pass data via angular data binding in HTML.